# How to set Gtk.Entry text to right aligned in PyGObject?

Tags: python, gtk3, pygobject

I am beginner with PyGObject.

```
entry = Gtk.Entry()
```

Is there some method for setting the text alignment for Gtk.Entry in PyGObject ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Gtk.Entry.set_alignment()` and configure `xalign` to `1` (`0` is left, `0.5` is centered, `1` is right).

Here is an MCVE:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class EntryWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(title='Entry Widget')
        self.set_size_request(200, 100)
        self.entry = Gtk.Entry()
        self.entry.set_text("Hello World")
        self.entry.set_alignment(xalign=1)
        self.add(self.entry)

win = EntryWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

[image: GUI]

Comment: @SanjayPrajapat: that is beyond the scope of the question, isn't it? You need to ask again, I'll be happy to answer.

Comment: ,i can post a question only once every 90 minutes.